# How to add Inner query for psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_schema_size('public'));
```

will return the size of schema "public"

Instead of "public", how would I pass all values returned by the query

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

so that it will print all the size of each schema present in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the function call on the result of the query:

```
select schema_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_schema_size(schema_name))
from   information_schema.schemata
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik :)  I was trying this inner query and function since 4 hours